# Choosing Random Background with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code returns no errors, but just leaves the overlay effects without the background picture:

```
$(function() {
    var totalCount = 8;
    var bg = Math.ceil(Math.random() * totalCount);

    $("html").css({
        "background": "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%), url(../img/bg0"+bg.toString()+".png) no-repeat center center fixed"
    });
});
```

Comment: i see you only use background style in the css method..why you need paranthesis { ..} for that..? can u try that without the brackets..i think the comma is not allowed in the value property of the method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("html").css({"background": "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%), url('../img/bg0"+bg.toString()+".png') no-repeat center center fixed"});
```

You should have `url('../img/bg0"+bg.toString()+".png')` i.e. the path inside url should be in single-quotes

Comment: Also, my directory to the image didn't require the "../" for some odd reason. Considering the css file is in a path below the root.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntx mistake - forget about " ' "

```
$(function() {
    var totalCount = 8;
    var bg = Math.ceil(Math.random() * totalCount);
    $("html").css({"background": 
             "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, 
              rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%), 
              url('../img/bg0"+bg.toString()+".png') 
              no-repeat center center fixed"});
});
```